# Fixtures Plugin Referential Integrity Exceptions In Grails

Tags: grails, one-to-one, fixtures, referential-integrity, bidirectional

I have an object Foo that has a bidirectional one-to-one relationship with Bar and another one with Baz. When I try to do a .load with Foo and only give it a Bar, I get referential integrity exceptions complaining that there isn't a Baz.

Should this really be the case? In a real world environment isn't it possible that there wouldn't be any matching Baz object in the database?

I tried manually setting baz:null in the fixtures load closure, but I still get the same thing. On a side note, when I only set properties (such as a simple string), everything works fine. It's only when I start setting relationships.

This is with Grails 2.2.4, Fixtures 1.2, and without the build-test-data plugin installed.

**EDIT**: I have the constraints specifying Baz to be nullable and unique. Just for giggles I tried adding the `blank` constraint too, but no luck.

```
static constraints = {
    baz nullable:true, unique: true, blank: true
}
```

**EDIT 2**: Here is a simplified version of the code:

```
class Foo {
    String someValue1
    String someValue2
    String whatever
    Bar bar
    Baz baz
    static mapping = {
        id composite: ['someValue1', 'someValue2'], generator: 'assigned'
        columns {
            bar([:]) { column name: 'some_other_value' }
            baz ([insertable:false, updateable: false]) {
                column name: 'some_value_1'
                column name: 'some_value_2'
            }
    }

    version: false

    static constraints = {
        //there are no constraints for Bar
        baz nullable:true, unique:true
    }
}

class Bar {
     String someOtherValue
     static hasMany = [foos:Foo]
     static mapping = { 
        id generator:'assigned', name:'someOtherValue'
     }
}

class Baz {
    String someValue1
    String someValue2
    String asdf

    static mapping = {
        id composite: ['some_value_1', 'some_value_2']
        version false
    }
}

class MyTest {
    def fixtureLoader
    @Before
    void setup() {
        fixureLoader.load {
            myBar(Bar, someOtherValue:"shibby")
            myFoo(Foo, someValue1:"test", someValue2:"test2", bar:myBar)
            //i also tried this
            //myFoo(Foo, someValue1:"test", someValue2:"test2", bar:myBar, baz:null)
        }
    }
}
```

Here is part of the exception:

> Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcBatchUpdateException: Referential integrity
>   constraint violation:  "FK190E74B120F4F2BC: MYSCHEMA.FOO FOREIGN
>   KEY(SOME_VALUE_1, SOME_VALUE_2) REFERENCES MYSCHEMA.BAZ(SOME_VALUE_1,
>   SOME_VALUE_2)"; SQL statement: insert into MYSCHEMA.foo (whatever,
>   some_other_value, some_value_2, some_value_1) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?,
>   ?, ?, ?) [23506-164]

**EDIT**: Sorry, I misspoke earlier. Bar has a many-to-one relationship with Foo.

Comment: Can you post a simple failing example?  Domain Classes and Fixtures would help

Comment: Okay, I just posted it.

Comment: You have the ID on Bar set to `generator:'assigned'`, but I don't see the id value being set anywhere.  Is that causing Bar to fail to save which then would cause a referential integrity constraint when you go to save Foo?

Comment: myBar(Bar, someOtherValue:"shibby") Is that not setting the id?

Comment: What is `hasMany` doing in Bar w.r.t a bidirectional one-to-one relationship?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your simplified version of code (except `hasMany` in Bar) *works* for me without any FK exception. Although I would prefer a different approach to achieve a true one-one bidirectional relationship if I am correct with the parent and child mapping.

Below is my setup which works fine without the FK constraint exception. Note that I have also mentioned in comments how would I achieve true one-to-one bidirectional assuming **Foo has one Bar and has one Baz**.

```
class Foo implements Serializable{
    String someValue1
    String someValue2
    String whatever

    //True one to one can be achieved by doing as below
    //static hasOne = [bar: Bar, baz: Baz]

    Bar bar
    Baz baz

    static mapping = {
        id composite: ['someValue1', 'someValue2'], generator: 'assigned'
        columns {
            bar([:]) { column name: 'some_other_value' }
            baz ([insertable:false, updateable: false]) {
                column name: 'some_value_1'
                column name: 'some_value_2'
            }
        }
        version: false
    }

    static constraints = {
        //baz nullable:true, unique:true
    }
}

class Bar {
    String someOtherValue

    //True one to one can be achieved by doing as below
    //Below entry makes the relation bi-directional
    //Foo foo

    static mapping = {
        id generator:'assigned', name:'someOtherValue'
        //Optional, added for clarity
        someOtherValue column: 'some_other_value'
    }
}

class Baz implements Serializable{
    String someValue1
    String someValue2
    String asdf

    //True one to one can be achieved by doing as below
    //Below entry makes the relation bi-directional
    //Foo foo

    static mapping = {
        id composite: ['someValue1', 'someValue2']
        //Optional, added for clarity
        someValue1 column: 'some_value_1'
        someValue2 column: 'some_value_2'
        asdf column: 'asdf'

        version false
    }
}

class MyTests extends GroovyTestCase {
    def fixtureLoader

    void setUp() {
        fixtureLoader.load {
            myBar(Bar, someOtherValue:"shibby")
            myFoo(Foo, someValue1:"test", someValue2:"test2", 
                     whatever: "whatever", bar: myBar)
        }
    }

    void testSomething() {
        Foo.all.each{println it.properties}
        Bar.all.each{println it.properties}
    }
}

//Bootstrap Test in Dev mode
new Bar(someOtherValue: 'shibby').save()
new Foo(someValue1:"test", someValue2:"test2", 
        whatever: "whatever", bar: myBar).save(failOnError: true, flush: true)
```

**Notes**

- Above I have used your exact simplified code but the `hasMany` relation in Bar.
- Constraints on `Baz` is optional.
- Fixtures works as expected.
- Columns are created in Foo as expected.
- `logSql` showed expected DML.
- To witness the table changes, I also BootStraped the same test data in dev mode following a `run-app`. I was able to see the expected table structure with data in it, using `dbconsole`.
- Following the general way of one-to-one bidirectional (mentioned as commented code), FKs are created in the child tables [`Bar` and `Baz`], so the explicit mapping you provided in the sample code would not hold good.
- The question will be more clear if the owning side of the relationship and the rationale behind having `hasMany` in Bar is mentioned.

Comment: I fixed this by changing the relationship between Foo and Baz to a true one-to-one relationship as you suggested. That is to say, static hasOne = [baz:Baz] on Foo, and a Foo field in Baz. Thanks for  actually trying this out; sometimes it takes someone to say "it works for me" :)